# meaning of the at once in a sentence

Tags: complex-sentences, philosophy

I am translating the book Missing Out: In Praise of the Unlived Life by Adam Phillips. It has this passage:

> There is, in other words, a difference between somebody saying
> something that makes one feel understood and somebody saying something
> striking. There is, or there can be, a difference between reading
> something intelligible and reading something that has a powerful
> effect; between words as procurers of experiences and words as
> consolidators of knowledge. There is a difference between the wish to
> comfort and assuage and the wish to provoke and unsettle. And we speak
> to each other and read for both these opportunities, and for other
> experiences as well. But it is the linguistic arts that seem at once
> hospitable to the notion of intelligibility, and in which
> intelligibility can be put into more or less intelligible question.

my problem is in this sentence:

> But it is the linguistic arts that seem at once
> hospitable to the notion of intelligibility, and in which
> intelligibility can be put into more or less intelligible question.

please confirm if this is the correct understanding of the sentence:

1- the linguistic arts are at the same time are hospitable to the notion of the intelligibility and in them the intelligibility can be put into question

please note that the text is difficult and needs reflection to understand. It is not a novel or a news in which you get the meaning by just looking at the text. This book is written in philosophy/psychoanalysis field.

Comment: For a sentence about being understood, this one is quite difficult. *smile*

Comment: I just need to know that I have understood correctly the grammar of the sentence not the meaning.

Comment: It's very odd grammar. I would have expected the sentence to read _...seem at once hospitable... and [another adjective]_

Comment: [**at once**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+once#:~:text=at%20once-,1.,simultaneously%3A%20Everything%20happened%20at%20once.) = *All at one time; **simultaneously***.

Comment: Where are these belows?  Why do you say "the below" instead of "the following" or "the cited" or "the enclosed" — or quite simply the optimal "this" or "these"? If you want to sound less foreign, try using the established and customary English demonstratives *this, that, these, those* instead of all these weird-sounding belows. I'm quite certain that I've never seen a below in my life. :)

Answer (score 1):

My judgement is that the sentence is ungrammatical.

- ' ... seem at once X and Y' is short for ' ... seem at the same time to be X and Y' or more commonly ' ... seem to be both X and Y'.

For example

- 'The foxes seem at once curious and wary'

is a (very formal, perhaps literary) shorter paraphrase of

- 'The foxes seem curious and/but at the same time they seem wary'.

Note that this is a metaphorical usage of 'at once' / 'at the same time', unlike the literal ('at the same instant') usage in 'computers can perform many tasks at once'. These phrases may be substituted by 'both' (or 'not only ... but also'):

- 'The foxes seem both curious and wary'

But 'seem in which intelligibility can be put into more or less intelligible question' is unacceptable.

I'd amend to

> But it is the linguistic arts that seem hospitable to the notion of
> intelligibility; further, *it would seem / it is a fact* that this
> intelligibility can be put into more or less intelligible question.

'To put N into question' for 'to investigate' (perhaps?) is highfalutin' too.

Comment: The lack of a suitable noun to refer back to ***the linguistic arts*** in that final clause doesn't seem like *that* serious an omission. Linguistics is both *hospitable..., and [is **something**] in which intelligibility can be put into **a** more or less intelligible question.* To me, the lack of that indefinite article is a rather more significant error/ typo /... (or maybe the writer intended plural ***questions***, I dunno).

Comment: 'Art is both open to criticism and in which criticism may lead to future movements'???

Comment: *Art is both open to criticism and **[is] something** in which criticism may lead to future movements*. No biggie.

Comment: No; 'both' / 'at once' strongly resist the deletion. A zeugma too far.

Comment: I'm not *endorsing* the text as presented. Just saying that the trivial lack of a suitable ***noun*** after ***and*** seems no more an impediment to comprehension than the missing ***article*** (which seems to pass without comment). I just don't see enough here to justify keeping the question open and formally *answering* it (for posterity?).

Comment: If it had been 'When it eventually did happen, it all happened at once' ('at once' = 'simultaneously, at the same time; literal', I'd agree. The metaphorical broadening ('The foxes seem at once curious and wary') where 'at once' = 'at the same time, figurative' = '**both**') is not too easy to find defined.

Comment: I didn't *actually* closevote when I posted my easily-found definition under the Q, but I'm still of half a mind to do so. Perhaps the mere fact that we seem to have different opinions as to whether "linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts" ought to be able to understand this *(slightly?)* defective text is evidence that I was right to stay my hand there!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what's being said. 'It is possible to understand the linguistic arts, and to formulate cogent questions to aid such understanding.'? How is that not redundant?

Comment: I just understand it as saying something along the lines of *Language is conducive to understanding / communication. [And] it allows us to embody such wisdom in **questions posed**, as well as **answers received***. That's to say, for me the primary focus of "at once" here is that intelligibility can be both delivered and received through language. A trite observation, but good enough for me! :)